# Android get bounding rectangle of a View

Tags: android

I'm implementing a drag and drop for an Android application. In order to know if the drop happens inside the drop target, I need to know the bounding rectangle of the drop target view. I would then see if the `getRawX/Y()` in the MotionEvent fall within this rect when I get the `ACTION_UP` action.

I realize I can call `getLeft/Right/Top/Bottom()` on the drop target view, but these are relative to the parent's container. It seems I need to know the "real" or raw values so i can compare them to the raw x, y in the MotionEvent.

Comment: wondering if i can use View.getLocationOnScreen() / getWidth() + getHeight()?

Comment: If calling from an `Activity`, `onCreate()` is too early, by the way. You have to do it in `onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus)` or later.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Yes, `View.getLocationOnScreen()` did the trick. For example,

```
private boolean isViewContains(View view, int rx, int ry) {
    int[] l = new int[2];
    view.getLocationOnScreen(l);
    int x = l[0];
    int y = l[1];
    int w = view.getWidth();
    int h = view.getHeight();

    if (rx < x || rx > x + w || ry < y || ry > y + h) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: How to use this method, what are parameters representing, what is view, what is rx, what is ry ?

Comment: `rx,ry` is the coordinate you want to test if it is within the bounds `view`.

Answer (score 41):

You can also use a Rect here:

```
private boolean isViewContains(...) {
    int[] l = new int[2];
    imageView.getLocationOnScreen(l);
    Rect rect = new Rect(l[0], l[1], l[0] + imageView.getWidth(), l[1] + imageView.getHeight());
    return rect.contains(rx, ry);
}
```

Less wordy, and possibly faster, but certainly (IMO) more readable.

Comment: Better yet, you could use View#getGlobalVisibleRect, e.g.:
`Rect rect = new Rect();`
`imageView.getGlobalVisibleRect(rect);`

Comment: Which parameter I have to pass? Draggable view??

Comment: private boolean isViewContains(final View imageView, final int rx, final int ry) should do it.

Comment: Why would creating an object and calling a function be faster than inlining the same logic?

Comment: In my case which I want to get a checkbox's rectangle within a viewHolder item when binding it, @Tony 's suggestion `getGlobalVisibleRect(rect)` did the trick. Only this way I could get a non-zero rectangle and use it as selection hot spot.

Answer (score 5):

This code takes into consideration, the perimeter of the `Views` involved and only returns `true` when the dragged `View` is fully inside the drop zone.

```
public boolean containsView(View dropZone, View draggedView){
     // Create the Rect for the view where items will be dropped
     int[] pointA = new int[2];
     dropZone.getLocationOnScreen(pointA);
     Rect rectA = new Rect(pointA[0], pointA[1], pointA[0] + dropZone.getWidth(), pointA[1] + dropZone.getHeight());

     // Create the Rect for the view been dragged
     int[] pointB = new int[2];
     draggedView.getLocationOnScreen(pointB);
     Rect rectB = new Rect(pointB[0], pointB[1], pointB[0] + draggedView.getWidth(), pointB[1] + draggedView.getHeight());

     // Check if the dropzone currently contains the dragged view
     return rectA.contains(rectB);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

### Kotlin Extension solution

Here is a combination of extension getters you can add to quickly get the x/y coordinated or the bounding box of any view

```
val View.screenLocation
    get(): IntArray {
        val point = IntArray(2)
        getLocationOnScreen(point)
        return point
    }

val View.boundingBox
    get(): Rect {
        val (x, y) = screenLocation
        return Rect(x, y, x + width, y + height)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `getGlobalVisibleRect`:

```kotlin
val rect = Rect()
view.getGlobalVisibleRect(rect)
val isContainedInView = rect.contains(x, y)
```