# How to get the rectangular perimeter of a view

Tags: android, android-layout, coordinates, android-relativelayout, android-view

I have a view and I need to get it's top and bottom location on the screen. So I run the following experiment:
Trying to figure out what hit rectangle does, I run the following experiment

```
int[] location = { 0, 0 };
myView.getLocationOnScreen(location);
Rect outRect = new Rect();
myView.getHitRect(outRect);
```

Then I print and got

```
outRect.top = 18
outRect.bottom = 138
location[0] = 216
location[1] = 387
```

I was expecting `outRect.top` and `location[1]` to be the same.

So, how do I get the top and bottom location of my rectangular view?

Comment: check it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5730240/android-get-bounding-rectangle-of-a-view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getLocationOnScreen()` returns the X and Y position of the view relative to the screen: you can calculate the bottom position by adding the value of getHeight() to the Y position. `getHitRect()` returns the position of the view relative to its parent, which is why you're getting different numbers.