# Get info from another view

Tags: android, view

I have several views, let's say 5 buttons. And how can I click on 1st button and then hold my finger on screen but move it to the 5th button so that when I release button I got information from 5th button and only 5th button. I've tried to use touch listener: detect Action_Down and Action_Up but understood that touch listeners are assigned to only one view(in this case view but it can also be assigned to containers too).

Thank you.

Comment: use Drag Listener

Answer (score 0):

Attach the `onTouchListener` to the view containing all these buttons, then you can check whether a button contains the `(x,y)` coordinates of the `ACTION_UP` using this code taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5730240/android-get-bounding-rectangle-of-a-view):

```
private boolean isViewContains(View view, int rx, int ry) {
    int[] l = new int[2];
    view.getLocationOnScreen(l);
    int x = l[0];
    int y = l[1];
    int w = view.getWidth();
    int h = view.getHeight();

    if (rx < x || rx > x + w || ry < y || ry > y + h) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```