# How to get the x coordinates of the end of a view in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am new to Android development and I am working currently on a game project...

I want to detect collision between two views (one moving only vertically and the other moving only horizontally). For this, I tried the following thing:

`if(egg[a].getX() >= (s2.getX()) && (egg[a].getX() <= (s2.getX() + s2.getWidth())) && (s2.getY() == egg[a].getY()))`

Here s2 and egg[] are the views. The above thing works but not efficiently. I mean like even if they are near enough but not touching each other even then the condition remains true. So what I want to know is that how to get the extreme right x-coordinate (ending x-coordinate) of `s2` view. I tried searching for this (even on SO) but did not get the desired answer. Please help me out. And if any other method is there to detect the collision then please do tell... I am using `java`.

Comment: try with `egg[a].getGlobleVisibleRect(rect);` to get all boundaries of view. After that you can get all coordinates easily

Comment: @EAS Please tell what is `rect`. Variable or something else. And if variables then how to define them, their data type and their values...

Comment: `Rect rect=new Rect();` //defineation
`rect.left` //x coordinate
`rect.top` //y coordinate
`rect.right` //x coordinate of end of view
`rect.bottom` //y coordinate of end of view

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5730240/android-get-bounding-rectangle-of-a-view